# How do we mention or tag a group member using Slack's Block Kit Builder?

Tags: slack-block-kit

I know I can tag a member using <@XXXXXXX> where XXXXX=member id. Is there any way to do the same, but tagging slack groups instead ? (slack groups does not seem to have a member id associated to it...)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Very similar to how you would mention a user, you show us we can do this by doing `<@UXXXXXXX>`. A public channel would require the use of a # symbol instead of the @ symbol. `<#CXXXXXXX>`.

You can check out the [Slack Documentation](https://api.slack.com/reference/surfaces/formatting#linking-channels) for more ways to mention users and user groups.

**Example**:

```
Why not join <#C024BE7LR>?
```

**Note**: the channel needs to be public.